# Как вывести текст из QTextEdit в переменную?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtextedit

Пытаюсь понять как вывести текст из редактора в переменную, окно программы запускается, но после нажатия кнопки (вызова функции) возникает такая ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'textEdit'

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('ok', self)
        self.pushButton.move(50, 50)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(click)

def click(self):
    text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
    print(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Example()
    form.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я отметил для вас что надо подправить

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textEdit.setPlainText('Hello World')
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('ok', self)
        self.pushButton.move(50, 50)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)             # self.click
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

# ---->        
    def click(self):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        print(text)
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Example()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]